# How can I detach a firebase listener in the useEffect hook cleaning function if the App component does not unmount

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, use-effect

the useEffect cleanup function is not being triggered when I sign-out using (firebase) and I get the error **Uncaught Error in onSnapshot: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.**
once I get redirected to the sign-in/ sign-up page.

I understand that the cleaning function get triggered if the component unmounts, but in my case the App Component doesn't unmounts (and It shouldn't), so the listener doesn't get detached

```
   function App() {
     const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState('')

     useEffect(() => {
      let unsubscribeFromAuth = null;

      unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async userAuth => {
        if(userAuth) {
          const userRef = await createUserProfileDocument(userAuth)

          userRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            setCurrentUser({
              id: snapshot.id,
              ...snapshot.data()
            })
          })
         }

        setCurrentUser(userAuth)
      })

      // the cleaning function is not being triggered because the App component is not unmounting (it shouldn't unmount anyways)
      return () => unsubscribeFromAuth()
    },[])

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            {
              currentUser
                ? <Redirect from="/" to="/userpage" />
                : <SignInAndSignUpPage currentUser={currentUser} />
            }
          </Route>

          <Route path='/userpage'>
            {
              !currentUser
                ? <Redirect from="/userpage" to="/" />
                : <UserPage user={currentUser} />
            }
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

my firebase security rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }   
  }
}
```

my signout button located in the userpage:

```
 <button
    onClick={() => {
      auth.signOut();
    }}
 >
   SIGN OUT
 </button>
```